# Load specific file with AJAX based on ID, attribute or other

Tags: jquery, ajax

Most online AJAX tutorials show how to fetch 1 file by clicking one element,for example like this:

HTML

```
<a class="ajaxLoader">Get file</a>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".ajaxLoader").click(function (event) {
         event.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
 url:"ajaxfiles/file1.html", 
 cache: false,
 success:function(result){
      $("#someDiv").html(result);
    }});
    });
});
```

Which works fine. But I would like to have is 100's of such anchors  (across different pages) that would each load a different file.
Is there a practical solution to this? 
What I don't want of course is to have:

```
<a id="id1">Get file </a>
<a id="id2">Get file</a>
<a id="id3">Get file</a>
```

etc... 
and keep updating my JS file with

```
$('id1').click(function()( // load file 1 with ajax )); 
$('id2').click(function()( // load file 2 with ajax ));
$('id3').click(function()( // load file 3 with ajax ));
```

etc...

I'm happy to give a separate ID/Attribute/Title/whatever to an element, but is there a way to match that to a correct file and avoid writing 100's of .click() functions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However you wish to identify your file is completely up to you. in this case, we assume each file is `file1`, `file2`, `file3`, etc....We also assume that you're actually using `id1`, `id2,`id3`, where the integer in this string is actually the integer corresponding with your file nomenclature.

```
<a id="id1" class="ajaxLoader">Get file </a>
<a id="id2" class="ajaxLoader">Get file</a>
<a id="id3" class="ajaxLoader">Get file</a>
```

Now simply split the `id` property on `id` and then take the `2nd element` in the array which will be everything `after id`, so in this case, `1`, `2`, `3`, etc. Then simply concatenate that into your URL path, and that's it.

```
$(".ajaxLoader").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var the_file_int = $(this).prop('id').split('id')[1]; //the number from id1/id2/id3, etc
    $.ajax({
        url:"ajaxfiles/file"+the_file_int+".html", 
        cache: false,
        success:function(result){
            $("#someDiv").html(result);
    }});
});
```

Comment: *sigh* - as always, spend 1+ hour researching, then ask on stackoverflow, get an answer in 1-3 minutes... Thank you :) I will prob. have a bit more complex ID names for categorization purposes, but I will manage the string operations myself from this point :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Given this HTML:

```
<a class="get-file-link" id="id1">Get file </a>
<a class="get-file-link" id="id2">Get file</a>
<a class="get-file-link" id="id3">Get file</a>
```

You can bind a click handler based on the class, then in the click event handler, get the id property, like so:

```
$('.get-file-link').on('click' function (evt) {
    var linkId = $(this).prop('id');
    // linkId now has the id property of whichever link was actually clicked.
    // Use that to construct the name of the file to download.
    evt.preventDefault();

});
```

Alternatively, you could use the HTML5 data attribute to associate the filename with the link in the HTML. For example:

```
<a class="get-file-link" data-filename="file1.html">Get file </a>
<a class="get-file-link" data-filename="file2.html">Get file</a>
...
<a class="get-file-link" data-filename="fileN.html">Get file</a>
```

Then use the .data method rather than the .prop method to get the filename, like so:

```
$('.get-file-link').on('click' function (evt) {
    var filename = $(this).data('filename');
    var url = "ajaxfiles/" + filename;
    // Make the ajax call to get url
    evt.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: +1 for data attribute info. I will try both methods and see what works best for me. Thank you!